# Only enable eslint in specific files

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, eslint

I really like eslint for es6 projects. Previously I've used it for new projects. Now I want to add it to a legacy project.

Fixing all pre-existing lint issues in one go is too much effort. Can I configure eslint (in `.eslintrc.js`) to only check files where I've explicitly enabled it with `/* eslint-enable */` or similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ESLint has no default-disabled state that can be toggled by a file comment. You might be able to use [`.eslintignore`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories) for this purpose, however. You can ignore everything and then gradually whitelist files as you migrate them by using `!` to un-ignore individual files. For example:

```
.
├── .eslintignore
├── .eslintrc.js
├── package.json
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── src
│   ├── index.js
│   └── module
│       └── foo.js
└── yarn.lock
```

Then your `.eslintignore` could look something like this:

```
# Start by ignoring everything by default
src/**/*.js
# Enable linting just for some files
!src/module/foo.js
```

In this case, `src/index.js` would be ignored, but it would lint `src/module/foo.js`.

Comment: This is an acceptable way to do it. I think you  have a typo though. `src/***/*.js` should be `src/**/*.js` no?