# Only enable stylelint in specific files

Tags: stylelint

This post shows how to [enable eslint for specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909553/only-enable-eslint-in-specific-files).

I would like to take a similar approach with `stylelint`.

This config works to ignore all of my css files in that directory:

```
"stylelint.configOverrides": {
  "ignoreFiles": "assets/styles/**"
}
```

Is there a way to include style linting on one (or more files) in my `assets/styles` directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that stylelintignore can be configured the same was as eslintignore!

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question correctly, simply create a `.stylelintignore` file in the root directory of your project with the following content:

```bash
# Ignore everything
**/*.css
# Enable Stylelint only for assets/styles directory
!assets/styles/**/*.css
```

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/ignore-code/#files-entirely